# How do I set up Freenas behind a Watchguard Firebox Firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, freenas

I tried to set up one of the Firebox's 4 interfaces in bridged mode, and then when I plugged in the Freenas machine, which already has a static IP, gateway and DNS servers assigned to it, it won't work, for some reason. It works outside of the Watchguard, though.